# DataBinding Oddity - Converter not called on the second pass

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding

I have a context menu that is defined as a resource and bound to the SelectedItem in a DataGrid, using a converter to get the display name of the current item, as in "Edit " or "Edit "

It works fine for the first selected item, but doesn't call the converter on the second (I have a break point in it that only gets hit on the first pass). BUT if I invoke the bound command on the second pass, it invokes on the newly selected instance as it should.

I use this technique with other ItemsControls and I can't spot anything wrong. Any ideas?

Cheers,
Berryl

Resource & binding

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="ProjectActivityContextMenu" x:Shared="true">
    ...
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding SelectedProjectActivity, Converter={StaticResource DeleteProjectConv}}" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" />
</ContextMenu>
```

Wiring

```
<DataGrid ...
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProjectActivity}" 
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
    ContextMenu="{DynamicResource ProjectActivityContextMenu}"
 >
```

UPDATE

This also happens if I declare it as part of the grid, like:

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu >
    ....
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding SelectedProjectActivity, Converter={StaticResource DeleteProjectConv}}" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" />
                </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Just checking, is the PropertyChanged event for "SelectedProjectActivity" property being raised correctly?

Also, what type of command is DeleteCommand?

Comment: @puppet. Good thought, and I do not raise my own propertyNotification in the setter of SelectedProject since it is synchronized by the framework. At least thats how I understand it and I see the value change when a different item is selected

Comment: @puppet. The command is a variation of Josh Smith's RelayCommand or whatever they call it these days. I suspected the CanExecute delegate also (which is true as long as the SelecedProject != null), but it looks fine and the command executes correctly on the correct SelectedProject. Maybe there is and UpdateTrigger setting I need? I am baffled

Comment: you still need a PropertyChanged notification on SelectedProjectActivity if you want other Bindings that use it to be updated. I assume the synchronization you're talking about is the ICollectionView.CurrentItem that is activated by setting IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True". This has no effect on anything you're using in this example.

Comment: @John. You are right, using INPC on the set fixed it. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're seeing is just a consequence of defining the ContextMenu as a Resource. Until you actually open the menu, it has no DataContext to apply the Bindings to so the converter isn't being called. This should hold even if you change the selection a few times without opening the menu. Once you right click and open the menu the DataContext is applied and the Bindings can be resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it also happens when the menu is declared as part of the grid, as in the end of my updated post.

Comment: The answer was really to trigger a property change, not changing the location of the resource.